# AWS EC2 set up key and non key authentication at same time

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, aws

I want to set up password based authentication (non key) on AWS EC2 ubuntu instance. But at the same time I want to keep the key based authentication also on the same instance. Will it be possible and how we can do that?

Comment: The pure password authentication is really dangerous for your instance, without additional security (if the server is accessible via Internet) it will be hacked soon! Here are listed few other methods (different from key based authentication) how to: [Secure an Ubuntu OpenSSH server from Brute force attacks...](https://askubuntu.com/q/903911/566421).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

To set up password based authentication (non key), you can achieve this by following the below setup,

**Step 1:** Create password for the root user

> sudo passwd root

**Step 2:** To allow root password, edit sshd_config file and set the "PasswordAuthentication" value as "yes"

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PasswordAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin  yes
```

**Step 3:** For key based authentication,

> sudo cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/

**Step 5:** After that make sure the "/root/.ssh/authorized_keys" file should start with ssh-rsa content

> no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10"

**Step 6:** Finally, to reflect your configuration changes, you need to restart ssh services, so use the below command.

```
sudo service ssh restart
```