# Virtual Machine Server and Multi Factor Authentication

Tags: server, ssh, virtualhost

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server, I run SSH and a virtual machine server, libvirt.

I plan on adding Google Multi Factor Authentication as another layer of security on top of key encryption and other hardening techniques.

My question is, will this work? Are there issues that I will run into? Is there a more compatible Multi Factor system to use with Libvirt and my Server?

I use Virtual Machine Manager on most of my systems but I also use PuTty with X11 on a Windows Box.

TL;DR: What issues will I encounter with Virtual Machine Manager and a Server with Multi-Factor Authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of science I took the plunge and enabled Multi factor authentication using the Google system. I don't know why I ever doubted Ubuntu, it worked!

For those interested in setting it up, I used the following two links to great success.

[Secure an Ubuntu OpenSSH server from Brute force attacks but without a firewall or SSH key pair?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903911/secure-an-ubuntu-openssh-server-from-brute-force-attacks-but-without-a-firewall/904035#904035)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04

And to actually answer the question this is what is seen when you have 2FA enabled and connect to a remote virtual host. 
[image: Success!]