# Cannot login with two-factor SSH

Tags: ssh, password, two-factor-authentication

In response to the users that flagged this as a potential duplicate, it is not. I *have* a SSH hardening solution, which I got off Canonical's ubuntu tutorials and is commonly repeated, but it isn't working, as I outlined below.

On my Ubuntu 18.04 box I've attempted to setup two-factor authentication for SSH per [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/configure-ssh-2fa#0), however when I attempt to login via SSH it fails. I'm prompted for my username as normal, then my password. No matter what it returns "Access denied" when I've entered my password. If I comment out

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

from /etc/pam.d/sshd then SSH works again, but obviously without two-factor. What is stopping my password from being accepted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure an Ubuntu OpenSSH server from Brute force attacks but without a firewall or SSH key pair?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903911/secure-an-ubuntu-openssh-server-from-brute-force-attacks-but-without-a-firewall) - read the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/904035/566421) of mine there.

Comment: In my case, I fixed this with sudo systemctl restart sshd.service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I got it to work. The .google_authenticator file was not created properly in my home directory (not sure why though, possibly I ran google-authenticator under the wrong user, possibly as root?), so after re-running it everything works fine.

Comment: You may accept your own answer to get this marked as Solved.