# Permission denied after two factor authentification activation

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I followed instruction on this [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#2-installing-and-configuring-required-packages) to get two factor authentification on ssh.

But since, I've done it, I get a permission denied when I try to connect using the usual user.

I'm using Ubuntu Server I only have one user on this machine and root isn't allowed to connect using ssh.

Do somebody has an idea ?

I've read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121571/cannot-login-with-two-factor-ssh) hear, but I can't Access my Server using ssh now.

Comment: To clarify, you have *no* access to the server now and closed the SSH connection used to configure 2FA? 

Comment: unwillingly yes 

Comment: But I got throught the whole tutorial.

Comment: If you have no access to the server, then you won’t be able to regain access unless you know how to hack into a Linux box … which is well beyond my skill set 

Comment: I will access the server on local-physical. Is there a way to understand what is the expected password for ssh login ?